# QuickBooks Desktop Integration required in php

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using QuickBooks PHP DevKit. I want to integrate QuickBooks Desktop with web service. I will be getting customers, invoices and sales receipts.
I am trying to get customers using this file.
`\dev\dev_ids_customers.php`
I am worried how to get token and realmID.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Start with this quick-start guide:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Using this code from GitHub:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Specially, you should be using the files in the docs/web_connector/ folder:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/web_connector

The file that you mention:

- /dev/dev_ids_customers.php

Is not related to QuickBooks desktop *at all*, and *will not work*. That file is for QuickBooks *Online*, which you are not using. Do not use this file. Use the files in the docs/web_connector/ folder that I have linked to above.

QuickBooks desktop files *do not have* realm IDs or tokens. You do not need them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I want to get customers, invoices and sales receipts. By using 
web_connector/example_web_connector_custom_fields.php
to import data. The web connector give me error.

Version:
PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /quickbooks/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector.php

Message:
-2: No registered functions for action: CustomerImport

Description:
Error message received from application via getLastError(): -2: No registered functions for action: CustomerImport

Please help me to get data from quickbooks using consolibyte library

Comment: We have support forums for answering general support requests: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/  Or, create a new topic on StackOverflow and *post your code* so that we can help you. Chances are, you haven't mapped your request/response functions to that action in $map.