# Quickbook enterprise account connect with php api

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Is it possbile to connect the Quickbook Enterprise account with the PHP API?
I have a Quickbook Enterprise account so i have to process the customer/invoice/payment using php api. Can any one please help me?

Comment: This question has been answered about a million times already. Please SEARCH first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045229/quickbooks-desktop-integration-required-in-php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049839/quickbooks-php-devkit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234743/consolibyte-quickbooks-php-to-add-simple-xml https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Hi Keith , this all refrence link tells about how to connect the Quicbook online account with API, but i am asking for Quickbook Enterprise account. There is a diff between these both right.

Comment: Did you actually look at the links above? The three StackOverflow links I posted are specifically about QuickBooks desktop (which includes Enterprise). The GitHub link I posted talks about BOTH QuickBooks Online AND QuickBooks desktop (including Enterprise). Please actually go and read the linked posts.